# Как отключить редирект для всех файлов, начинающихся на 1c_exch_.....?

Tags: .htaccess, маска

В htaccess у меня есть следующее:

```
<FilesMatch "1c_exch_blabla.php$">RewriteEngine off</FilesMatch>
```

То есть, отключаем редирект на https для конкретного данного файла.
Вопрос такой: а как отключить редирект для всех файлов, начинающихся на 1c_exch_..... ?

Answer (score 0):

подсказал коллега

```
<FilesMatch "1c_exch_*$">
```